# Correct installation order to a clean asp.net development enviroment

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, development-environment

I want to setup a Win7 virtual machine to develop using Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.Net 3.5.

I don't know what the best order to install what I need. I will need to install:

a) Visual Studio 2008
b) IIS
c) Service Packs for Visual Studio and/or .Net Framework

My last try was bad, I cannot do my old ASP.Net 3.5 web app to work on Win7  (works fine on Win2003).

Another questions are, if I choose to use Visual Studio 2010 (to develop ASP.Net 3.5), it's recommended? And the installation order will change?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to actually use the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer.](http://www.microsoft.com/Web/downloads/platform.aspx) This tool will walk you through installing ALL of the components you need to host a web application. Pick your platform (PHP, ASP.NET, etc), an optional application (DasBlog, etc), and even choose to download Visual Studio 2008 Web Developer + SQL Express. It will install everything for you seamlessly. I've used it and I highly recommend it for a "clean" install.

Comment: Sorry Will, if I only knew you were going to post this first... can't we still be friends?

Comment: nice! it's compatible with Win7?

Comment: AFAIK, yes it is. You may have to use v2.0 Beta, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd install IIS first, then Visual Studio 2008. The framework will come with VS.NET 2008. If all goes wrong learn to use [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx)